# Where to get patent litigation dockets?

Tags: litigation, docket, court, documents

Is there a way to get court trial documents for specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [PACER](https://www.pacer.gov/findcase.html), but it's not free.

And there is [search.rpxcorp.com](https://search.rpxcorp.com) (used to be free) - patent litigation search. You 'll just need to register an account for that.

Comment: There is also a http://www.plainsite.org/.